# What should my gemfile look like (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have trouble setting up my gems correctly while working with Heroku. Can someone tell me what it should look like? Here's what it looks like currently:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sinatra', '1.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you specify what is the exact error/issue you are facing ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli I don't have a problem yet, but I am just preparing. What do I need to do with the sqlite3 and PG gems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support running rails apps using `sqlite3` so you should remove that and use `pg` instead.

Or you could set that for your development env only and set `pg` for production.

But it's always recommended to run your local env as similar as possible to your production, so that you won't get any surprises when you go live.